# List aligned the wrong way

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_content">
           &#169; 2012 Company, Inc.
           <ul>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
                <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
           </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

This is my CSS

```
/* FOOTER */ 
#footer {
    position: relative; 
    margin-top: -60px; 
    text-size:12px; 
    height: 60px; 
    clear:both; 
    background-color: blue; 
    line-height: 60px; 
    text-align:right
} 
#footer_content { 
    width: 940px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer ul { 
    list-style: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
}
#footer ul li { 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 5px; 
}
#footer ul li a { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-right: 5px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
#footer ul li a:hover {  }​
```

Currently the copyright is on the right and the links are on the left. It should be the other way around. What adjustment are you meant to make to move them?

Comment: I copied your code examples into a jsfiddle, but the results are just blank.  Perhaps you can tweak the code a bit to show us what you're seeing?  [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m28rU/)

Comment: @TLS it's not blank - the `#footer` has a negative margin of 60px, so it's just hidden

Comment: @TLS - the margin and background color in the CSS hides the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty much agree with what Space Beers says but there are ways to improve this.

HTML:

```
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer_content">
           <ul>
               <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
               <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
           </ul>
           <div class="copyright">
               &#169; 2012 Company, Inc.
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>​
```

CSS:

```
    #footer {
        position: relative; 
        margin-top: -60px; 
        text-size:12px; 
        height: 60px;
        background-color: blue; 
        line-height: 60px; 
        text-align:right
    } 
    #footer_content { 
        width: 940px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #footer ul { 
        float:right;
        list-style: none; 
    }
    #footer ul li { 
        display:block;
        float: left; 
        margin-right: 5px; 
    }
    #footer ul li a { 
        font-weight: bold; 
        margin-right: 5px; 
        text-decoration: none; 
    }

    #footer .copyright{
        float:left;
    }
```

This should be completely browser compatible.

Comment: `div` is an element without meaning. It is only meant to be used to wrap other elements. In this case what you're marking up is definitely a paragraph of text thus the appropriate element to use is of course the `p`. I also don't see the point in the two wrapping `div`s (`#footer` and `#footer_content`).

Comment: Good point!  I was assuming that he was not able to use any html5 tags, but if you are using html5 you should absolutely improve the semantics of my markup by using <footer> and wrapping the copyright in a <small> tag.  Also utilizing classes instead of ids would be a welcome change.  In this instance, there is no reason to wrap #footer_content in anything, again just working with the given markup.

Answer (score 0):

Put your company info in a containing div and float that left.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_content">
       <div class="company_info">&#169; 2012 Company, Inc.</div>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
          <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
</div>​

.company_info{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use `display:inline;`in li class

Comment: if anybody gives vote down please comment the reason also to helpful us